# What Statistical Method is Useful for Comparing Two Different Groups?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I'm working on a project and I want to know what statistical method would be useful to see if my hypothesis is true.

The project I'm working on is Calculus Rentention.

My hypothesis is: do students, who had took advanced math courses in high school, tend to continue studying advanced math in college?

My plan is to separate the datas in two groups: students who took at least one AP math (Group A), and students who didn't take AP math (Group B). Then, I'm planning to find the probability of switching major (or leaving the STEM field) from each group.

After getting two probabilities, what statistical method should I use to prove if my hypothesis is true or false?

Any suggestion would be appreciated. And please feel free to provide different way to play with this hypothesis if you have different idea(s)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have $n$ data points (data of the student academic history) and you want to be able to predict whether they continue studying advanced math in college as you suggest. In this case, a good choice of model would be simple logistic regression. You would encode the response (in this case whether or not they continued in advanced math) as $Y_i = I(A)$ where we let $A$ be the event of continued advanced study in college. So far, you mentioned you would include two groups as predictive features in the model. This would also be binary encoded, since they are categorical variables (being in group A or group B). Then,
$$
\pi_i=P(Y_i=1) = \frac{exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1I_{GA})}{1 + exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1I_{GA})}
$$
where we let $GA$ denote membership to group A. You could do further research from here on these methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I researched about simple logistic regression model and I found out that this model should be used when I have one nominal variable with two values (male/female, dead/alive, etc.) and one measurement variable. I'm very weak with vocabularies, so could you define my nominal variable with two values and one measurement variable?

Comment: Sure! Your nominal variable would be "continued to study advance math in college", for which the two values would be "did continue" coded as a 1, otherwise "did not continue" coded as a 0. Your measurement variable (or predictor - just meaning what you've observed through the data to help predict the nominal variable) would be which group the students belong to -- with values A (for group A) or B. But since, this is also nominal (categorical), it must also be coded as either 0 or 1 to make sense for the math. Would you be doing this project in R, python?

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick replies. I will be doing this project in R!